# Load more Yii code except extension in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

How to create load more code in "yii" except extensions.

Can anybody tell me how to do this
How to call controller and get data without whole page refresh

Answer (score 0):

No sure about what you are asking but I think you are talking about doing some ajax calls:

In your view you need to perform an ajax call and your controller you are going to check if the controller is requested in an ajax call or a classic one

```
public function actionView($id)
{
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
            //The client is usign ajax to request this controller action
            //the renderPartial will only render the 'partialView' view
            $this->renderPartial('partialView', array(
                'model' => $model
            ));
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
        //No ajax so we render everything (header, layouts, ...)
        $this->render('view', array(
            'model' => $model 
        ));
    }
```